# Calculate combined filesize of thousands of files

Tags: linux, bash, du

We have a software package that performs tasks by assigning the batch of files a job number. Batches can have any number of files in them. The files are then stored in a directory structure similar to this:

```
/asc/array1/.storage/10/10297/10297-Low-res.m4a
...
/asc/array1/.storage/3/3814/3814-preview.jpg
```

The filename is generated automatically. The directory in `.storage` is the thousandths digits of the file number.

There is also a database which associates the job number and the file number with the client in question. Running a SQL query, I can list out the job number, client and the full path to the files. Example:

```
213     sample-data     /asc/array1/.storage/10/10297/10297-Low-res.m4a
...
214     client-abc      /asc/array1/.storage/3/3814/3814-preview.jpg
```

My task is to calculate the total storage being used *per client*. So, I wrote a quick and dirty bash script to iterate over every single row and `du` the file, adding it to an associative array. I then plan to echo this out or produce a CSV file for ingest into PowerBI or some other tool. Is this the best way to handle this? Here is a copy of the script as it stands:

```
#!/bin/sh

declare -A clientArr

# 1 == Job Num
# 2 == Client
# 3 == Path
while read line; do
    client=$(echo "$line" | awk '{ print $2 }')
    path=$(echo "$line" | awk '{ print $3 }')

    if [ -f "$path" ]; then
        size=$(du -s "$path" | awk '{ print $1 }')
        clientArr[$client]=$((${clientArr[$client]}+${size}))
    fi
done < /tmp/pm_report.txt

for key in "${!clientArr[@]}"; do
    echo "$key,${clientArr[$key]}"
done
```

Comment: Calling `awk` three times, `echo` twice and `du` once for every line of a file is always going to take forever. Try to run whatever you need to run once and accumulate results within a single invocation of `awk`, `python` or a database.

Comment: See: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/118235)

Comment: Is there an actual question in your question?

Comment: The *best* way would be to add a column to your database with the file size.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sadly, the database is controlled by the software. I can talk to them about adding this as a feature, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- you have GNU coreutils `du`
- the filenames do not contain whitespace

This has no shell loops, calls `du` once, and iterates over the pm_report file twice.

```sh
file=/tmp/pm_report.txt

awk '{printf "%s\0", $3}' "$file" \
| du -s --files0-from=- 2>/dev/null \
| awk '
    NR == FNR {du[$2] = $1; next}
    {client_du[$2] += du[$3]}
    END {
      OFS = "\t"
      for (client in client_du) print client, client_du[client]
    }
  ' - "$file"
```

Comment: I'm getting an awk syntax error at "printf %s0" pointing at the % symbol.

Comment: In case it helps, I am running GNU Awk 4.0.2 in a Docker container provided by the software developer.

Comment: Oops, I used the wrong quotes. use `printf "%s\0",` with double quotes. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using file `foo`:

```
$ cat foo
213     sample-data     foo          # this file
214     client-abc      bar          # some file I had in the dir
215     some            nonexistent  # didn't have this one
```

and the awk:

```
$ gawk '                             # using GNU awk
@load "filefuncs"                    # for this default extension
!stat($3,statdata) {                 # "returns zero upon success"
    a[$2]+=statdata["size"]          # get the size and update array
}
END {                                # in the end
    for(i in a)                      # iterate all
        print i,a[i]                 # and output
}' foo foo                           # running twice for testing array grouping
```

Output:

```
client-abc 70
sample-data 18
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error at `@load "filefuncs"` pointing at the l in load. This is GNU Awk 4.0.2 provided by the software developer in a Docker container.

Comment: [Feature history](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Feature-History.html) mentions that `--load` came in version 4.1 but extensions are mentioned in the earlier versions. I have no idea if they existed or how to use them in your version. Maybe it's time to upgrade...